# TinyMCE Font Size Menu

Tags: tinymce-4

For some reason I can't get the font menu to appear in TinyMCE.  Here is my code:

```
$("#page_text_mce").tinymce({
    script_url : '/admin/public/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
    plugins: [
     "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
     "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
     "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
   ],
   toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect fontselect | fontsize",
   toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
   image_advtab: true ,

   external_filemanager_path:"/admin/filemanager/",
   filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/admin/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
    height: 330,
    width: 1050
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong property value on `toolbar1` for font size, it should be `fontsizeselect`. Not `fontsize`.